# Ruby on Rails - How to rearrange view of comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I have created an application where Users can create Projects and make Comments on these Projects. Right now, I have ability for users to make comments on each Project page.

Question 1: The order is currently showing comments and then the option to submit a new comment below this. When I try to rearrange it so that it shows submit a comment before listing of comment I get NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. What do I need to do so that the comment submission box is above the current comments.

Question 2: Right now, the comments are being listed with most recent on bottom. How do I flip the order so most recent is on top?

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :project_id, :user_id
  validates :content, presence: true

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  scope :newest, order("created_at desc")
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user! 

  def create
    project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = project.comments.create!(params[:comment])
    redirect_to project_path(project)
  end
end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
 <!-- Show Comments -->
          <p class="comment_header">Comments:</p>

          <% if @project.comments.blank? %>     
            <p>No comments made yet for this project.</p>        
          <% else %>        
            <% @project.comments.each do |comment| %>   
              <div class="comments">        
                <p><%= comment.content %></p>
                <span>By <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
              </div>
            <% end %>       
          <% end %>

          <!-- Add Comments -->

          <% if signed_in? %>
            <p class="comment_header">Add Comment:</p>

            <span class="comment">
                <%= form_for([@project, @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "span7", :rows => "3" %>
                  </div>

                  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

                  <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
            </span>

          <% else %>

            <p class="comment_header"><%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %> to post comments.</p> 

          <% end %>
          <!-- end of comments section -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) That doesn't require something special. I think you just made a error in the mark-up (... html.erb). Make sure you take the whole form_for / end part and don't move the f/text_area outside of that.

2) For sorting in reversed order (last comment first). Sort DESC on the created_at date in your comment model.

comment.rb

```
scope :newest, order("created_at desc")
```

show.html.erb (fixed to show this instead)

```
<% @project.comments.newest.each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: thanks. figured out. used <% @project.comments.newest.each do |comment| %> and works now

Comment: rogier, do you know how I can paginate the comments? can this be used? <%= will_paginate @comments %> ?

Comment: you need -for that to- work a gem 'will_paginate'. https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate or build something yourself.